# Identifying user of a webapp

Tags: java, c#, javascript, python, authentication

For a small webapp I want to be able to identify a user.

The issue is, if the user cheats in some manner, I want to be able
to forbid him the usage of my application.

I already have done extensive research on that topic, but to no avail.

What is not an option:

- cookies: can be disabled or deleted (to easily overridable)
- ip adress: is dynamic or hidden through NAT
- MAC adress: cannot be retrieved (as far as I know, or at least not without terrifying the user)
- Flash: is not supported on a wide range of devices

This is a central part, so I can decide which technology to use along
this decision.

What are the options I have? (especially I do not want that the user gets a security warning as this is often the case with java applets)

Some kind of unique machine identifier would be okay.

**-edit-**

What I want to protect against:

It should be some kind of discussion board about recent topics.
There will be people that proof that they have not the attitude to discuss in the public, e.g. insult other people etc.

And I want to have a possibility to keep these people away.

There will be somekind of login. But what keeps people from creating simply another account and keep going?

Fingerprinting seems to be to weak, as is has some well known flaws. Using a bank account is way to hard to use, at least since there is nothing you can buy right now, it will keep users from using the site.

Isn't there something in the middle? Like a device id, which keeps users from one device away, despite it might be wrong, this would do the job in a vast majority of cases I believe.

Comment: It could help if you identified what it is you're trying to protect against. Are you attempting to keep a site from being compromised? If you're trying to prevent denial-based attacks, you may be able to do something on the web server layer or through caching. Is it some kinda functionality on a website you're trying to keep someone from cheating against? If so, would some kinda authentication requirement work? Are you trying to protect some kinda functionality of your site against bots or something along those lines? Maybe CAPTCHA-like solutions would work for you

Comment: Ask for the user's SSN?

Comment: I think this is a problem that has already been solved a few times. Please avoid kidding me, I want to get answers about what my options are here.

Comment: It's never been solved well. Some people use IP addresses and browser fingerprinting, but that's easy to bypass. The only solution that seems to work well is trusting banks and governments. You could ask the user to sign up with a bank account or credit card and verify the user's authenticity that way. That will work acceptably, but you're still open to credit card thieves.

Comment: Thought there has to be something in the mid of a minimum and a total solution. Something like a machine id. The browser fingerprint seems to be to weak and IP addresses are dynamic at least.

Comment: @TheDarkTrumpet Please have a look at the updated question. And many excuses, I did not see your comment, just the one of raptor. Do not know why.

Comment: Can't you just ask them to subscribe to the webapp, then they would have to log in to use it & you could easily ban offenders (who, like those banned from s.o, would immediately register again with yet another fake email address ;-)

Comment: @Mawg Just as I described in the edited question 5 hours ago. They login, insult people, get banned, create another account, insult again. I want some measure to get that handled. This is the exact problem.

Answer (score 5):

There is no 100% solution to your problem.

A user can use a wide range of strategies to bypass any possible action: delete cookies, use a VPN, even change its device (mobile phone, pc, laptop). You mentioned them.

> What are the options I have?

That said, IP adress and a [browser fingerprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) is your best bet. There are libraries for JAVA (and probably C#) that can extract a fingerprint from the `HTTP Request`. But again the user could just change his browser signature or switch to another device.

Therefore is might be helpful to change the idea behind it from "completely locking a user out" to "making it hard for a user to gain access."

**Edit:**

"A device id" would basically be the MAC address, which can not be obtained via a HTTP request. So no, there is no device id you could use. A device fingerprint is the closest thing you can get.

**An Idea:**

You could use a mobile app to authenticate a user. An app could obtain a device id (MAC address or IMEI for Android). Use the device id from the phone to register a user. You'll only need the mobile app for registration. If you ban a user, he won't be able to register again using the same phone. (This is of course not 100% reliable, but more reliable than anything browser based)

Comment: I already have some login using credentials. All I want is to be able to see "user x is logged in from device y". If the user gets blocked because of fraud, I want to be able to say "new user from device y is denied". There is some chance of public computers get denied wrong, but this would be acceptable for me. I just want to keep the new platform clean from cheaters. Is fingerprinting a way to get this going?

Comment: Browser fingerprint is a good idea (+1). Wrt, "user could change it", that applies to all methods - but first the user has to know which method you are using, which will be difficult if you write server side code. Yah, I know it's security through obscurity, but it helps a little. Good idea, as casual users are unlikely to guess this one.

Comment: @jHilscher Good idea. With the drawback of making it hard for users to register and use the platform. It shall be as easy to use as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The only fool proof way is to force users to identify themselves with an authentication mechanism.

Identification is the "Who are you?" question, and the answer can be a user name, real name, email address, browser finger print, etc.

Authentication is "Who are you and prove it!".  In computer security this is implemented by requiring the user to supply a minimum of two things, such as the user name and a MATCHING password which have been established in advance.  In this regard "things" are grouped into one of three categories:

1. "Something you possess" (An object such as a One-time pad)
2. "Something you know" (such as a piece of secret information, typically a password), and
3. "Something you are" (presented as a digitally encoded representation of a piece of your body, eg a fingerprint scan)

Access control is always a trade-off between convenience and security.  To make a system more secure you necessarily have to make it less convenient to use.  The most convenient system is where anybody can just do anything without having to supply any credentials.  Such systems are quite rare these days, but some public Wikis still allow anybody to edit the content.  On the end of the spectrum high security systems, such as the ones controlling nuclear reactors, require you to be physically at the system console in a room where you must book your access in advance.  Everything else falls in somewhere in between.

After Identity and Authentication comes the third concept:  Authorization, which means "Is the identified user allowed to perform the requested operation"

Authorization is meaningless without an **authenticated** identity, because if  you are trying to prevent misuse of a system without authenticating the users, then you simply can not be sure that users are who they claim to be.

So basically it amounts to you having to force your users to supply identity credentials, which can be set up through a registration process.

The question you must ask is how much do you care about preventing misuse of your system and how much inconvenience will your users be willing to put up with.  People are quite used to having to log in to web based services, and often quite fed up with misuse such as spamming and cheating, so most people will accept that they must register to continue using your system.

Are we talking about cheating at online voting stations?  Cheating about having received a soup kitchen meal ticket?  An online board game?  A (small) banking application?  A school subject testing application?  A Job interview screening test for a programmer position?  These all have different requirements because the users are different people from different backgrounds and with different skills and resources.

**Update:**

Since you are already authenticating your users, one concept (that I am currently investigating for my own application) is using a 3rd-party to do the hard work in providing user identification and authentication.  Basically for my application I will be using a form of OpenID.  I will not be supporting local registrations, users will only be able to register using their Facebook/Google+/LinkedIn accounts.  My objective is different though - I want to make it very easy for users to sign up.  Your objective is to eliminate disposable accounts by making it harder for users to register disposable accounts.

This process alone will not make it impossible to set up disposable accounts.  What I would suggest and what other web sites, including StackExchange, does to a greater-or-lesser degree:  Combine the identification with a trust-score.  Basically a new user should not immediately have the authority to post.  They need to first earn trust by some means.  SlashDot allows you to filter and by default filters out some low-score posts.  Many sites require a new user to be vetted by an existing "resident".  Forums display a user's registration date and number of posts as a measure of trust.  Sites like SE also allows existing users to "vote" or "thank" users for their valuable and helpful posts.

The concept is to authorize the action of posting and/or rate posts.

Posts from users with a low trust score may need to first be scrutinized and "accepted" by a trusted user before it becomes visible to the public.

**Update 2**

Higher forms of security may require more than two of the three types of things a user must provide to authenticate themselves.  A very common thing for people to "have" is a phone and you can check it by sending a text message with a unique code, which the user must enter back into the web site to prove that they have the phone with that number.  Once they have entered the phone number, and you have checked that the number is not on a list of banned numbers, you can grant them a higher trust score.

With such a system you can change your existing system without inconveniencing your existing users too much.  For example allow all users to register and log in.  In order to post they must either get a high trust score or they must supply a phone number which you can verify.  The phone number requirement does not completely make it impossible for people to misuse the system, but makes it rather difficult to create many disposable accounts.

Note that this system have some disadvantages.  Services like Amazon SNS only sends text messages to American numbers.  Messaging providers to other countries charge a fee to deliver the message, which could be a problem if your web service cannot afford the cost.

One other mechanism for identifying the user device exists but only if the user accesses the service through an application installed on a mobile device.  An app can read the device identification number.  This can also be used as a means of "trusting" a user because people only have so many physical devices, but web based apps does not support reading this type of information from the device.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I already know these concepts, but I am quite new to webapps, hence this question. It is some kind of public discussion about recent topics. There will be people that prove they have not the attitude to talk in the public in a proper way. These are the people I want to keep out. Perhaps they are technically skilled, but the site shall be easy to use, despite registration. So some "computer id" would be great, but as written, I am quite new to webapps, and this is an issue to clear before starting on that project.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use phone verification? A user can't have 'n' no. of phones or at max of 2 or 3
When you ban a person, ban his phone no. too so that he can't verify again.

Simply use on-call/text user a code on his phone to enter into the browser.
This will not only help you identify the genuine users also help you keep spammers away.

Comment: This keeps possible users from signing up at all. Giving away a phone number to write comments is a hard barrier for a lot of people. But of course, it is possible solution to the problem.

Comment: Well, I'm just asking for a verification, apart of an email, Just add a phone verification system to verify the user by sending him a code to enter on the website.

Most of the big organisations are using this technique, e.g.. are pretty clear, Facebook, Microsoft, Twitter, Google they all use it. That's certainly a foolproof solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add some benefits for long-term user or disadvantages for new users like more strict rate limiting or CAPTCHA. You can also use a reputation system. One can create a new account if banned, but without all the advantages of long-term user.

Comment: If one can comment with no reputation, it will not solve the problem of keeping people away that insult other people.

Comment: It depends how hard/soft solution you want. Maybe comments of low-reputation users can be less visible and comments of high-reputation users can be more visible. There will likely be some active members that will read all (including the less visible) comments and upvote them or downvote them and flag them as inappropriate. This might be good-enough solution.